# Tag creation and deletion

Tags: support

Recently, for a answer I gave for a question about Super Sentai and their costumes, I mentioned a couple of times the ***Tokusatsu*** genre. I thought it would be kind of nice to create this tag, since it envolves a bunch of these series from the Japanese TV. For a while it was there since I created it and it was approved. Then I got some information to add to it and suddenly it wasn't there anymore.

I received no updates about it, it simply vanished. Was it deleted? Are things just like that, here?

Comment: Was the tag applied to any questions?  Don't forget that tags which are not associated with questions - usually due to question deletion - are deleted - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/236563

Comment: @Chenmunka Yes. To this question: [Why do Super Sentai (Power Rangers) teams wear spandex suits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79484/why-do-super-sentai-power-rangers-teams-wear-spandex-suits/79485#79485)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what happened here but we don't create tags just because they're "nice to have".

If the question was **specifically** about the Tokusatsu genre *itself* (rather than movies *in* the genre) then that's an appropriate reason to create it otherwise I'm not sure it's necessary.

If the question wasn't about the **genre** itself then there really isn't any need for it unless it's part of an ID question.

I saw the question and, I believe, it was already tagged with [power-rangers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-rangers) and [super-sentai](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-sentai)...what did this new tag **add** that required it to be created and added to the question?

Comment: Understood. It seemed to me that it would be a nice addition. Well, _Tokusatsu_ is a rather important approach to the question, since the _Super Sentai_ franchise was a major impact to the _Tokusatsu_ genre around those years, costume included. Something that I mention. But ok, I'll refrain from taking a part on tags.